# Android saving dialog selected option to textview

Tags: android, dialog, textview, save

i´m using this code to make a onclick dialog window with choices, but i need to save the selected option as a text of a textview how?
Thank you.

public Dialog onCreateDialogSingleChoice() {

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence[] array = {"Redbull", "Monster", "Rockstar", "Shock", "Burn", "Semtex"};

    builder.setTitle("Select Brand")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(array, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })

            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }) ;

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to save the selected option as a text of a textview how?

Use `onClick` to get selected item from AlertDialog:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  String strSelectedItem=array[which];
  // show strSelectedItem in TextView
}
```

Comment: but array[which] is still int how to save it into string?